# How can I print member variable?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Item {
protected:
    string modelName;
    int price;
    string itemId; // “modelName-seqNumber”
    static int seqNumber; // initialValue = 1
public:
    virtual void print() const = 0;

    void setname(const string& _name)
    {
        modelName = _name;
    }
    string& getitemId()
    {
        return itemId;
    }
};

class Monitor : public Item {
    const int size;
public:
    int seqNumber = 1;
    Monitor(const string& _name, const int _price, const int _size)
        : size(_size)
    {
        setname(_name);
        price = _price;
        itemId = modelName;
        itemId += '-';
        itemId += seqNumber;
    }
    void print() const {
        cout << modelName << ', ' << itemId << ', ' << price << ',' << size << endl;
    }
};

class CPU : public Item {
    const int speed;
public:
    int seqNumber = 1;
    CPU(const string& _name, const int _price, const int _speed)
        :speed(_speed)
    {
        setname(_name);
        price = _price;
    }
    
    void print() const {
        cout << modelName << ', ' << itemId << ', ' << price << ',' << speed << endl;
    }
};

class ItemList {
    vector<Item*> items;
    void copyItem(const ItemList& list) {
        for (const auto item : list.getItem())
            addItem(item);
    }
public:
    ItemList() = default;
    ItemList(const ItemList& list) {
        copyItem(list);
    }
    ItemList(ItemList& il)
    {
        for (const auto item : il.items)
            items.push_back(item);
    }
    vector<Item*> getItem() const { return items; }

    void addItem(Item* const _item) {
        items.push_back(_item);
    }
    void print() const {
        for (const auto item : items)
            item->print();
    }
    void removeItem(const string& _name)
    {
        for (vector<Item*>::iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); it++)
            if ((*it)->getitemId() == _name)
                it = items.erase(it);
    }
};
```

Above are classes.

and below are main function.

```
int main() {
    ItemList list1;
    {
        CPU cpu1("Intel", 200, 5); // modelName, price, speed
        CPU cpu2("Intel", 300, 7);
        list1.addItem(&cpu1); list1.addItem(&cpu2);
        Monitor monitor1("Samsung", 1000, 40); //modelName, price, size
        list1.addItem(&monitor1);
    }
    cout << "Section 1" << endl;
    list1.print();
    {
        ItemList list2(list1);
        cout << "Section 2" << endl;
        list2.print();
        list2.removeItem("Intel-2");
        cout << "Section 3" << endl;
        list2.print();
    }
    {
        ItemList list3;
        list3 = list1;
    }
    cout << "Section 4" << endl;
    list1.print();
}
```

Hi, I'm studying c++ and I have a question!

I want to print modelName but when I run this code, some strange numbers were printed.

and also ',' wasn't printed.

I tried to debug my code but I failed.

What is the reason? I need your help!

and thank you for your attention!

Comment: Looks like you're taking references to a lot of local variables, which then go out of scope. Once a local variable goes out of scope, it's gone forever, and any attempts to access it result in undefined behavior, which is a fancy way of saying "everything is messed up"

Comment: "I tried to debug my code but I failed".  It's definitely good that you tried!  Q: What exactly did you try?  For example, are you using an IDE (like Eclipse)?  Or a command-line debugger (like GDB).  Exactly what "didn't work"?

Comment: Please review [ask], in particular the parts about presenting your question before showing any code and reducing your code to a [mre]. Focus on one problem at a time. Maybe -- if you have simplified your code enough -- try adding the reasons you believe your code should work perfectly.

Comment: Related: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/5023438)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    CPU cpu1("Intel", 200, 5); // modelName, price, speed
    CPU cpu2("Intel", 300, 7);
    list1.addItem(&cpu1); list1.addItem(&cpu2);
    Monitor monitor1("Samsung", 1000, 40); //modelName, price, size
    list1.addItem(&monitor1);
}
```

This declares two objects in the inner scope, `cpu1` and `cpu2`, passes a pointer to them to `addItem`, which saves them in its internal vector. Same thing for `monitor1`.

After this scope ends, `cpu1`, `cpu2`, and `monitor1` go out of scope and get destroyed. Their pointers in the vector are now pointing to destroyed objects, and using those pointers later results in undefined behavior, and the result of that is the garbage output that you are seeing.

Comment: I assume the teacher falls into traditional and now dated pattern of C "always pass structures by pointer" i.e. by address, avoiding a copy. One can see that alot in POSIX API. Once upon a time in C that was most effective way, now most calling conventions may imply such. In this case it assumed that class should make copy anyway, but that's C agreement, not C++!

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several bugs, I will point them out one by one.

Pushed the pointed to a local variable that is no longer lived after the first scope

---

```cpp
    {
        CPU cpu1("Intel", 200, 5); // modelName, price, speed
        CPU cpu2("Intel", 300, 7);
        list1.addItem(&cpu1); list1.addItem(&cpu2);
        Monitor monitor1("Samsung", 1000, 40); //modelName, price, size
        list1.addItem(&monitor1);
    }
```

Try to print a string with char type:

---

```cpp
cout << modelName << ', ' << itemId << ', ' << price << ',' << size << endl;
```

Add number to string, which won't work:

---

```cpp
itemId += seqNumber;
```

I have fixed your code by:

1. Replace the local objects with pointers:

```cpp
    CPU* cpu1 = new CPU("Intel", 200, 5);  // modelName, price, speed
    CPU* cpu2 = new CPU("Intel", 300, 7);
    list1.addItem(cpu1);
    list1.addItem(cpu2);
    Monitor* monitor1 =
        new Monitor("Samsung", 1000, 40);  // modelName, price, size
    list1.addItem(monitor1);
```

2. Add virtual destructor to the base class

```cpp
  virtual ~Item() = default;
```

3. Add clone function for all class, to avoid reference freed objects:

```cpp
class Monitor : public Item {
  const int size;

 public:
  int seqNumber = 1;
  Monitor(const string& _name, const int _price, const int _size)
      : size(_size) {
    setname(_name);
    price = _price;
    itemId = modelName;
    itemId += '-';
    itemId += std::to_string(seqNumber);
  }
  virtual Item* clone() override {
    return new Monitor(this->modelName, this->price, this->size);
  }
  void print() const {
    cout << modelName << ", " << itemId << ", " << price << ',' << size << endl;
  }
};
```

4. Append number to string with `std::to_string`

```cpp
itemId += std::to_string(seqNumber);
```

5. Add deep copy for the objects:

```cpp
  void copyItem(const ItemList& list) {
    for (const auto item : list.getItem()) addItem(item->clone());
  }
  ItemList(ItemList& il) {
    for (const auto item : il.items) items.push_back(item->clone());
  }
```

6. Add `operator=`

```cpp
  ItemList& operator=(const ItemList& list) {
    for (auto* p : items) {
      delete p;
    }
    items.clear();
    copyItem(list);
    return *this;
  }
```

7. Call free in the destructor to avoid memory leak

```cpp
  ~ItemList() {
    for (auto* p : items) {
      delete p;
    }
  }
```

8. The remove item function have dealed with iterators wrongly

```cpp
  void removeItem(const string& _name) {
    for (vector<Item*>::iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end();)
      if ((*it)->getitemId() == _name) {
        auto pre = *it;
        it = items.erase(it);
        delete pre;
      } else {
          ++it;
      }
  }
```

Finally the code works smoothly, generally the pointers should be `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_pointer` here to be mordern c++, if you like to see it, I will update the answer.
[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P73Tr9c9P)

---

The `shared_ptr` version is done, easier to maintain, no manually memory management now, I highly recommend it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Item {
 protected:
  string modelName;
  int price;
  string itemId;         // “modelName-seqNumber”
  static int seqNumber;  // initialValue = 1
 public:
  virtual void print() const = 0;
  virtual ~Item() = default;

  void setname(const string& _name) { modelName = _name; }
  string& getitemId() { return itemId; }
};

class Monitor : public Item {
  const int size;

 public:
  int seqNumber = 1;
  Monitor(const string& _name, const int _price, const int _size)
      : size(_size) {
    setname(_name);
    price = _price;
    itemId = modelName;
    itemId += '-';
    itemId += std::to_string(seqNumber);
  }
  void print() const {
    cout << modelName << ", " << itemId << ", " << price << ',' << size << endl;
  }
};

class CPU : public Item {
  const int speed;

 public:
  int seqNumber = 1;
  CPU(const string& _name, const int _price, const int _speed) : speed(_speed) {
    setname(_name);
    price = _price;
  }

  void print() const {
    cout << modelName << ", " << itemId << ", " << price << "," << speed
         << endl;
  }
};

class ItemList {
  vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> items;
  void copyItem(const ItemList& list) {
    for (const auto item : list.getItem()) addItem(item);
  }

 public:
  ItemList() = default;
  ItemList(const ItemList& list) { copyItem(list); }
  ItemList(ItemList& il) {
    for (const auto item : il.items) items.push_back(item);
  }
  ItemList& operator=(const ItemList& list) {
    items.clear();
    copyItem(list);
    return *this;
  }
  ~ItemList() = default;
  vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>& getItem() const { return items; }

  void addItem(std::shared_ptr<Item> _item) { items.push_back(_item); }
  void print() const {
    for (const auto item : items) item->print();
  }
  void removeItem(const string& _name) {
    for (auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end();)
      if ((*it)->getitemId() == _name) {
        it = items.erase(it);
      } else {
        ++it;
      }
  }
};

int main() {
  ItemList list1;
  {
    auto cpu1 =
        std::make_shared<CPU>("Intel", 200, 5);  // modelName, price, speed
    auto cpu2 = std::make_shared<CPU>("Intel", 300, 7);
    list1.addItem(cpu1);
    list1.addItem(cpu2);
    auto monitor1 = std::make_shared<Monitor>("Samsung", 1000,
                                              40);  // modelName, price, size
    list1.addItem(monitor1);
  }
  cout << "Section 1" << endl;
  list1.print();
  {
    ItemList list2(list1);
    cout << "Section 2" << endl;
    list2.print();
    list2.removeItem("Intel-2");
    cout << "Section 3" << endl;
    list2.print();
  }
  {
    ItemList list3;
    list3 = list1;
  }
  cout << "Section 4" << endl;
  list1.print();
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3EfeK7vhW)

Comment: Thanks! but I can't fix main function! Only I can fix my classes.

Comment: @iamianpark Your `main` function is buggy, why won't you fix it?

Comment: because it's a skeleton that I  can't fix. My teacher taught me not to fix it! lol

Comment: @iamianpark Your teacher is wrong this time, all people will make mistakes